# Opening a table from another mdb file with ADO in MSAccess

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to access a table from another mdb file. This isn't something a linked table can fix, please don't suggest it.

Edit: This is part of an archive tool that creates a backup file of the backend of the database from a certain date range, and then deletes the data. Before I delete the data, it was suggested that I check and make sure all the data copied over to the created backup. (IE, if the worst case scenario happened and the share folder lost connection or something, and not all the data copied over, but the access database deleted that data anyway)

If there's a way to create a linked table in access and then delete the link in the end WITH VBA, not manually, maybe that would work(?) but I was hoping to do it this way so hopefully it wouldn't cause the database to bloat up as much as it has been in the past.

I'm trying to check if all my data copied over to a backup file before I delete the ones in the current database.

```
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
rs.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _
                 "Dbq=Backup.mdb;DefaultDir=C:\Fish;"
```

I'm having trouble here with the syntax. I know it works with currentdb, but what if the table is in a different mdb file? I tried with DefaultDir=C:\Fish and DefaultDir=C:\Fish\ Is there something I'm missing or is this a lot more complicated then what I should attempt?

The rest of it I think I understand how to get the fieldvalues to compare, but trying to connect to a table in a different mdb file is giving me trouble.

Comment: *"This isn't something a linked table can fix, please don't suggest it."* - Please [edit] your question to explain why you believe that you cannot use a linked table.

Comment: Would you consider just copying your entire .MDB file as a backup? Then the file copy either works or it doesn't. When you start getting complex backup and archiving strategies against an access database that might indicate it's time to consider moving to SQL Server

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I have that option already, but this one is to, I guess, "Slim down" the database in use. It backs up to a specified Date and then deletes it from the original database. It was just a requested tool and I was trying to comply. Also, yes sql server is what I want, but I don't really have a say in what database programs we can and can't use. I'm just following orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: exactly like Gord already said in his comment, I can't see a reason against using a linked table either.

But in the end it doesn't really matter if you create a linked table and open a local `Recordset` on it, or if you open a `Recordset` directly on the table in the other Access database.

So I'll show solutions for both ways:

---

### 1. The approach from your question

Your connection string works for me, but there are mistakes in the rest of your code:

- An `ADODB.Recordset` doesn't have a property `ConnectionString`...it's called `ActiveConnection` instead.
- You need to actually create a new `ADODB.Recordset` before you try to set the connection string or open the Recordset

The following code works for me:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.ActiveConnection = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _
                 "Dbq=Backup.mdb;DefaultDir=C:\Fish;"

rs.Open "select * from foo"
```

---

## 2. Using a linked table

Create it:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC", ";DATABASE=C:\Fish\Backup.mdb", acTable, "TableName", "TableNameLocal", False
```

*Note: `TableName` is the original name of the source table, and `TableNameLocal` is the name that the linked table will have in your local database. (You can use the same names if you want, of course)*

Delete it:

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "TableNameLocal"
```

Comment: There's also the `SELECT * FROM [;Database=C:\folder\otherDb.mdb].[tableName];` trick to create a temporary link "on the fly".